# Flutter desktop windows log crash stack

Tags: flutter, stack-trace, crash-reports

Question: How to get the crash stackTrace in flutter desktop windows?
(Windows 11, Flutter 3.3.1)

My flutter desktop app works perfectly fine in debug mode but when I try the release mode, it crashes on a specific page using `CustomScrollView()`. Cannot replicate the issue in debug mode.

The release mode is made via:
`flutter build windows --release`

The app becomes unresponsive for about 1-2 seconds then it shuts down.

I have tried this in my Main():

```
Future<void> main() async
{
    runZonedGuarded(() async
    {
        runApp(const MyApp());

    }, (exception, stackTrace) async {
    
        SomeWriteToFileFunction('crash.log', stackTrace.toString());
    });

}
```

Doesn't do anything on crash. No files are created.

Windows Event Viewer shows info about the app crash but it doesn't contain anything useful (or I can't find it)

```
Faulting application name: abc_win.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x631d8041
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000015bfe808000
Faulting process id: 0x8ec
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8c5a7e17f4c6a
Faulting application path: C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\abc_win.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 67780c52-5a4b-4587-b162-8f369679a888
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

There's also the report.wer file:

```
Version=1
EventType=BEX64
EventTime=133073543046672092
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=133073543048207465
ReportStaabc=268435456
ReportIdentifier=d99f87a7-35d4-4382-8270-bc40efc7e758
IntegratorReportIdentifier=67780c52-5a4b-4587-b162-8f369679a888
Wow64Host=34404
NsAppName=abc_win.exe
OriginalFilename=abc_win.exe
AppSessionGuid=000008ec-0001-0024-6a4c-7fe1a7c5d801
TargetAppId=W:00063358eda8b5e9931bb29afbe762d309ee00000904!00001ec762621b3dc8a4b1cec35b92bfda12eb84a05f!abc_win.exe
TargetAppVer=2022//09//11:06:29:21!0!abc_win.exe
BootId=4294967295
ServiceSplit=439210136
TargetAsId=790534
UserImpactVector=808452912
IsFatal=1
EtwNonCollectReason=1
Response.BucketId=ad62618b52f4e16b264eeec482a26f59
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=1607484644790529881
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=abc_win.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=631d8041
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=StackHash_76a1
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=00000000
Sig[6].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[6].Value=PCH_C1_FROM_unknown+0x0000000000000000
Sig[7].Name=Exception Code
Sig[7].Value=c0000005
Sig[8].Name=Exception Data
Sig[8].Value=0000000000000008
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.22000.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=76a1
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=76a173c26a6dc2e3cd83ac8fd9f8bdb9
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=7b3f
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=7b3f634c955ac91fe3f1e745337a968a
UI[2]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\abc_win.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\abc_win.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\audioplayers_windows_plugin.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\desktop_drop_plugin.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\desktop_lifecycle_plugin.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\flutter_acrylic_plugin.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\native_context_menu_plugin.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\url_launcher_windows_plugin.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\webview_windows_plugin.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\flutter_windows.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.22000.1_none_271a8fad6a2d1b1e\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFPlat.DLL
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UIAutomationCore.DLL
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d9.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RTWorkQ.DLL
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxcore.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\WebView2Loader.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dcomp.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\directxdatabasehelper.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_d5ebba24696ee1d8\nvldumdx.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msasn1.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cryptnet.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\drvstore.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\devobj.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wldp.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_d5ebba24696ee1d8\nvwgf2umx.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\system32\directmanipulation.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\system32\dataexchange.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3dcompiler_47.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\abc.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
OsInfo[0].Key=vermaj
OsInfo[0].Value=10
OsInfo[1].Key=vermin
OsInfo[1].Value=0
OsInfo[2].Key=verbld
OsInfo[2].Value=22000
OsInfo[3].Key=ubr
OsInfo[3].Value=918
OsInfo[4].Key=versp
OsInfo[4].Value=0
OsInfo[5].Key=arch
OsInfo[5].Value=9
OsInfo[6].Key=lcid
OsInfo[6].Value=1033
OsInfo[7].Key=geoid
OsInfo[7].Value=244
OsInfo[8].Key=sku
OsInfo[8].Value=48
OsInfo[9].Key=domain
OsInfo[9].Value=0
OsInfo[10].Key=prodsuite
OsInfo[10].Value=256
OsInfo[11].Key=ntprodtype
OsInfo[11].Value=1
OsInfo[12].Key=platid
OsInfo[12].Value=10
OsInfo[13].Key=sr
OsInfo[13].Value=0
OsInfo[14].Key=tmsi
OsInfo[14].Value=221786468
OsInfo[15].Key=osinsty
OsInfo[15].Value=2
OsInfo[16].Key=iever
OsInfo[16].Value=11.1.22000.0-11.0.1000
OsInfo[17].Key=portos
OsInfo[17].Value=0
OsInfo[18].Key=ram
OsInfo[18].Value=65277
OsInfo[19].Key=svolsz
OsInfo[19].Value=1862
OsInfo[20].Key=wimbt
OsInfo[20].Value=0
OsInfo[21].Key=blddt
OsInfo[21].Value=210604
OsInfo[22].Key=bldtm
OsInfo[22].Value=1628
OsInfo[23].Key=bldbrch
OsInfo[23].Value=co_release
OsInfo[24].Key=bldchk
OsInfo[24].Value=0
OsInfo[25].Key=wpvermaj
OsInfo[25].Value=0
OsInfo[26].Key=wpvermin
OsInfo[26].Value=0
OsInfo[27].Key=wpbuildmaj
OsInfo[27].Value=0
OsInfo[28].Key=wpbuildmin
OsInfo[28].Value=0
OsInfo[29].Key=osver
OsInfo[29].Value=10.0.22000.918.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628
OsInfo[30].Key=buildflightid
OsInfo[31].Key=edition
OsInfo[31].Value=Professional
OsInfo[32].Key=ring
OsInfo[32].Value=Retail
OsInfo[33].Key=expid
OsInfo[34].Key=fconid
OsInfo[35].Key=containerid
OsInfo[36].Key=containertype
OsInfo[37].Key=edu
OsInfo[37].Value=0
OsInfo[38].Key=servicinginprogress
OsInfo[38].Value=0
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=BEX64
AppName=abc_win
AppPath=C:\Work\Flutter\abc_win\build\windows\runner\Release\abc_win.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=7A236311865A0102D270683706237FBC
MetadataHash=-941757982
```